# Sharepoint 2007: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have a list that gives the above error when attempting to add a new record to it. Here's the class in it's entirety:

```
Partial Class NextExclusionNo
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Private listName As String = "Exclusions List"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim curYear As String = Now.Year.ToString
    curYear = Mid(curYear, 3)

    Dim curMonth As String = Now.Month.ToString
    If curMonth.Length < 2 Then
        curMonth = "0" & curMonth
    End If

    Dim curDay As String = Now.Day.ToString
    If curDay.Length < 2 Then
        curDay = "0" & curDay
    End If

    Dim curObsPrefix As String = "E" & curYear & "-" & curMonth & "-"

    Try
        Using site As New spSite("http://localhost/exclusions")

            Using web As spWeb = site.openweb()

                Dim list As SPList = web.Lists(listName)

                Dim query As New spQuery
                query.query = "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Exclusion_x0020__x0023_' />" & _
                "<Value Type='Text'>" & curObsPrefix & "</Value>" & _
                "</BeginsWith></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Exclusion_x0020__x0023_' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>"


                Dim listItems As spListItemCollection = list.getItems(query)

                Dim newReportNo As Integer = 1

                If listItems IsNot Nothing AndAlso listItems.count > 0 Then
                    Dim lastReportNo = listItems.item(0).item("Exclusion_x0020__x0023_")
                    Dim licBits() As String = lastReportNo.split("-")
                    Dim lastNo As Integer = CInt(licBits(2))
                    newReportNo = lastNo + 1
                End If

                Response.Write(getFullReportNo(newReportNo, curObsPrefix))

            End Using

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Error:" & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Function getFullReportNo(ByRef licNo As Integer, ByRef prefix As String) As String

    Dim lic As String = licNo.ToString
    While lic.Length < 3
        lic = "0" & lic
    End While

    Return prefix & lic

End Function



End Class
```

The above is nested within a Try/Catch block.  Can anyone help me diagnose and remedy the above code block?  Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my analysis only column name which you have specified may give this error. Validate your column name and share me your findings.

Comment: Also getFullReportNo could throw this exception as we don't know whats inside. But stacktrace would reveal that.